# How do I set the state of a NSSwitch in Swift for a Mac application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I was making a MacOS app in Xcode with a switch and I need to set its state from the code.

**How can I do that?**

I know that for IOS I can do it with `switch.setOn()`, but that doesn't work for MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out, in swift it is

```swift
deathSwitch.state = NSControl.StateValue.on
```

to turn it on and

```swift
deathSwitch.state = NSControl.StateValue.off
```

to turn it off.

Comment: Swift  is a type inferred language `deathSwitch.state = .on`